# How do I name my model if the table describes a journal (accounting)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, naming-conventions

Model name is usually a singular name of some entity. And table name is a plural form of the word.
For example `Transaction` is stored in `transactions` table.

But there are cases when a whole table is described by singular word, means a scope of entities. For example: journal, log, history.
And there no more precise name for a single row besides "entry" or "item". But model named `ThingsJounralEntry` looks messy, and simple `ThingsJournal` is confusing, because an instance doesn't describe any actual journal, but single entry.

Is there a common naming approach for such cases better than described above?

Comment: Does your journal have accounting entries? If it does I would use `AccoutingEntry` or `AccountingRecord` (I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure what an accounting journal is.)

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia thanks, it's quite a right direction to move. Just need to think what is a single item actually is, not about the whole collection. `Record` suffix fits one of my actual cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to show that there are actually two naming issues in dance. One is regarding the elements of your collection, which you ask explicitly. The other one is regarding the collection itself, which is rather implicit. In fact, when you refer to `Journal` you feel compelled to clarify (accounting). This means that your collection class would be better named `AccountingJournal,` which would remove the ambiguity.

Now, since the description you provide of these objects (collection and elements) is a little bit succinct, I don't have enough information as to suggest an appropriate name. However, in order to give you some hints I would recommend considering not just the nature of the elements, but the responsibility they will have in your model. Will they represent entities or actions? If the elements are entities (things) consider names that denote simple nouns that would replicate or be familiar with the language used by accountants. Examples include `AccountingEntry` or `AccountingRecord.` If your elements represent actions then use a suffix that stresses such characteristic, for example, `AccountingAnnotation` or `AccountingRegistration.` Another question you can ask yourself is what kind of messages these elements will receive? For instance, if they will represent additions and subtractions of money you might want to use `AccountingOperation` or `AccountChange.`

Whatever the situation dictated by the domain you should verify that your naming conventions sound as sentences said by actual domain experts: "[this is an] accounting record of [something]" or "add this accounting record to the journal" or "register this accounting operation in the journal" or even "this is an accounting operation for subtracting this amount of money," etc.

The (intellectual) activity of naming you objects is directly connected with the activity of shaping your model. Exercise your prospective model in your head by saying aloud the messages that they would typically receive and check that the language you are shaping closely reproduces the language of the domain. In other words, let your objects talk and hear what they say, they will tell you their names.